# Concurrent Queue with enqueue and dequeue using Stack as underlying data structure

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, stack, queue

This is a mix of data structure and multi threading concept based question. (This is only for understanding and learning purpose)

A Queue with FIFO behavior needs to be implemented by having underlying data structure as Stack.
Enqueue and Dequeue need to be parallel and need not block each other, i.e. enqueue thread must not wait for dequeue thread.

For java, I could only find the blocking version of this problem where enqueue and dequeue are blocking for each other.

Below is my attempt for this, please correct me if I am wrong or in case I missed something.

1. Two Stacks : addStack and removeStack with individual Lock Objects addLock and removeLock
2. Enqueue operation : enqueue inside synchronized block on addLock, once item added, invoke notifyAll on addLock
3. Dequeue operation : If removeStack is empty then addStack is checked if it is empty , if not then all the elements from addStack are popped and pushed to removeStack
4. pop the element from removeStack and return

Below is the java code :

```
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Queue Implementation with Stack as underlying data-structure and with
 * parallel (almost) enqueue and dequeue
 * 
 * @author krishna_k
 *
 */
public class Queue {

    private Stack<Integer> addStack = new Stack<>();
    private Stack<Integer> removeStack = new Stack<>();
    private final Object addLock = new Object();
    private final Object removeLock = new Object();

    public void enqueue(int item) {
        synchronized (addLock) {
            addStack.push(item);
            addLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public int dequeue(){
        int value = 0;
        synchronized (removeLock) {
            if (removeStack.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    synchronized (addLock) {
                        while (addStack.isEmpty()) {
                            addLock.wait();
                        }
                        while (!addStack.isEmpty()) {
                            removeStack.push(addStack.pop());
                        }
                    }
                }catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    //code to log the exception e
                }
            }
            value = removeStack.pop();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still possible that Enqueue and Dequeue block each other. With the requirement to use `Stack` internally, it’s impossible to prevent this, even if your code did not contain any `synchronized`, as `Stack` has already `synchronized` methods and regardless of how you do it, there must be a transfer at some point of time.

Comment: @Holger That is the part of the question, and its only for learning purpose Hence internal data structure is Stack. Now even if We use simple arrays or array list or any other collection then also transfer will need to be done hence I could not see a 100% parallel solution.

Comment: hmm ok may be a double eneded linked list will be 100% parallel but the case for which I am not able to think is when at a point we will have a single node left and enqueue and dequeue threads try to execute

Comment: With the right algorithms, the critical section of updates reduces to an atomic operation. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does the trick.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the input, I will go through `ConcurrentHashLinkedQueue`

Comment: No “`Hash`”, just [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)